# Ubuntu hanging on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I have a Toshiba Satellite e205 dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7. I just upgraded to 12.04 and I've been having an issue with the OS hanging on shutdown. It will close all the windows and go to the splash screen and then hang there indefinitely.

At first I thought the problem was related to Dropbox - if I turned Dropbox off or didn't connect to the internet it would shut down fine. I uninstalled Dropbox and that helped, but it still will occasionally exhibits the same problem. It seems anecdotally as if the longer I have the computer running the more likely it is to fail on shut-down.

Any ideas on what might be happening or how to troubleshoot would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Since [at least one other person](http://askubuntu.com/a/167191/22949) is having this, maybe it's due to a bug, even though we don't know what triggers it or under what conditions it occurs. I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Can you give a summary of applications you installed besides Dropbox. Did you remove dropbox completely (removing all of it's configuration files using `purge` option)?

Comment: This bug affects me too. Did you report it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you log out and then shut down from the login screen, this problem does not occur. But that is a workaround, rather than a solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try and press escape while it's shutting down to see the shutdown log statements. That might help you find out what's causing it. Either way, if none of your OS'es are complaining about uncleanly unmounted file systems, it shouldn't be a problem (except for the inconvenience of course).